# echo JSON_ENCODE($json) only contains data for last record

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am trying to use json_encode to echo some data back to my ajax call, but I seem to receiving only a portion of the data, specifically the last record.  In the query below, when I did `$q->num_rows();` it correctly returns the correct number of rows, 6.  However, when I look at the resulting JSON object, I see that it only has the last pair of values for row 6.  The data for rows 1-5 is nowhere to be found.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
function myAjaxFunction(){
    $muni = $this->input->POST('muni');
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT SaleYear AS Y, NewSaleType AS T, count(*) AS C, format((sum(SalePrice) / sum(Quantity1)),0) AS R FROM tblsales WHERE  tblsales.SaleYear > 2007 AND tblsales.Quantity1 > 2000 AND (tblsales.NewSaleType = 'Industrial') AND tblsales.Municipality = '".$muni."' GROUP BY T,Y ORDER BY T,Y");
    $json_SaleYear = array();
    $json_AvrgRate = array();
    foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
        $json_SaleYear = $row['Y'];
        $json_AvrgRate = $row['R'];
    }
    $json['Y'] = $json_SaleYear;
    $json['R'] = $json_AvrgRate;            
    echo json_encode($json);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: `$json_SaleYear[] = $row['Y'];` and `$json_AvrgRate[] = $row['R'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have declared `$json_SaleYear` and `$json_AvrgRate` as array but not used array index to define value in `foreach` loop ,so its having only one row record i.e last record ..

change only part of your code this

```
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
        $json_SaleYear[] = $row['Y'];
        $json_AvrgRate[] = $row['R'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the arrays with values in the `foreach` loop, instead of appending to the array. So on each iteration of the loop, the `$json_SaleYear/AvrgRate` variables are getting overwritten with the current row's information. Once the loop completes, they contain only the last row's info.

Instead of updating the variables like this,

```
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
    $json_SaleYear = $row['Y'];
    $json_AvrgRate = $row['R'];
}
```

You should append to the arrays like this,

```
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
    $json_SaleYear[] = $row['Y']; // Note the []'s.
    $json_AvrgRate[] = $row['R'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following

```
$json_SaleYear = array();
$json_AvrgRate = array();
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
    $json_SaleYear = $row['Y'];
    $json_AvrgRate = $row['R'];
}
$json['Y'] = $json_SaleYear;
$json['R'] = $json_AvrgRate;
echo json_encode($json);
```

with:

```
$json = array( 
    'Y' => array(),
    'R' = array()
);
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
    $json['Y'][] = $row['Y'];
    $json['R'][] = $row['R'];
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score -1):

Though you have declared $json_SaleYear and $json_AvrgRate as array but you are setting its values as string. The correct format is below

```
function myAjaxFunction(){
    $muni = $this->input->POST('muni');
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT SaleYear AS Y, NewSaleType AS T, count(*) AS C, format((sum(SalePrice) / sum(Quantity1)),0) AS R FROM tblsales WHERE  tblsales.SaleYear > 2007 AND tblsales.Quantity1 > 2000 AND (tblsales.NewSaleType = 'Industrial') AND tblsales.Municipality = '".$muni."' GROUP BY T,Y ORDER BY T,Y");
    $json_SaleYear = array();
    $json_AvrgRate = array();
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
      $json_SaleYear[$counter] = $row['Y'];
      $json_AvrgRate[$counter] = $row['R'];
      $counter++;
    }
    $json['Y'] = $json_SaleYear;
    $json['R'] = $json_AvrgRate;            
    echo json_encode($json);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: I agree there is no need to use counter but in no way the answer is wrong so that it should be down voted.